# extern c linkage errors in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, extern-c

I have a simple c++ Visual Studio project:

```
#include "test.h"

test::test()
{
}

test::~test()
{
}
```

HEADER:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
class test
{
public:
    test();
    ~test();
};
```

When I compile test.cpp I get many errors in the vc/include files relating to extern c as given below. They only appear when I add the line:

```
#include <string>
```

I tried this test because another project suddenly stopped working.
I tried repairing Visual Studio, but it did not help.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)      this declaration may not have extern 'C' linkage    testextern  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception    369
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error (active)      more than one instance of overloaded function "std::operator==" has 'C' linkage testextern  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\exception    334
>
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   C2894   templates cannot be declared to have 'C' linkage    testextern  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\xtr1common   194

Comment: Have you by any chance gave your file a `.c` extension?

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding might help. Give it a try!

Comment: No, it is cpp. I simply created an empty project, using the template, and added the include string. I tried cleaning, rebuilding, even uninstalling and installing VS.